# Need help finding where the function below is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $f(z) = \mathrm{Log}\biggl( \frac{iz + 1}{-iz + 1} \biggr)$, where $\mathrm{Log}$ denotes the principal branch of the logarithm.

I can see that $T(z)=\frac{iz+1}{-iz+1}$ needs to not be in $(-\infty, 0]$.

So points in $T^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$ need to be avoided.

$T(z)$ is a Möbius transformation so I can find the inverse: $$T^{-1}(z) = \frac{z-1}{iz+i}.$$
How do I determine what the image of $(-\infty, 0]$ is under $T^{-1}$?

I understand that any Möbius transformation is determined by it's image on three points. I evaluate the image of the inverse on the following nice points:
\begin{align*}
 &T^{-1}(0) = i,\\
 &T^{-1}(-1) = \infty,\\
 &T^{-1}(\infty) = -i.
\end{align*}
I'm not seeing what information this is giving me, i.e., I don't see what the image of $T^{-1}$ is and would appreciate some help finding it. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you meant $(\infty,0]$ where you typed $(0,\infty]$. Möbius transformations map lines to either lines or circles. Since our image contains $\infty$, it must be a (portion of a) line. $T*{-1}$ maps our ray to the portion of the imaginary axis from $i$ to $\infty$ to $-i$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, yes that's a typo.  And I could sense that it must be a line but I'm not exactly sure what that line is. What line goes from $i$ to $\infty$ to $-i$? Is it the line that starts from $i$, goes to the top and around, stopping at $-i$?

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, you've got it. It must preserve ordering, so it's the ray from $i$ to $-i$ through $\infty$, i.e. $[i, i\infty] \cup [-i\infty, -i]$ i.e. the imaginary axis minus the line segment $(-i, i)$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I was not thinking about the ordering, but now that you mentioned: can you please explain why the correct ordering isn't given by $(-1, 0, \infty)$? That is, why isn't the line the one that goes from $-i$ to $i \infty$ with the point $i$ in between?

Comment: For the same reason you did the calculation in the order you did: when traveling along the ray $[-\infty, 0]$ from right to left we encounter $0$ then $-1$ then $\infty$ in that order (it has a natural total order on it as a subset of $\mathbb R$) and mobius transformations preserve ordering, so starting from the preimage of $0$ and moving toward the preimage of $-\infty$ we will find somewhere in the middle the preimage of $-1$. The only way this can happen is the way I described (there are only two directions on the imaginary axis to go starting at $i$, and only one works)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Is $-\infty$ the same as $\infty$? The reason I ask is because I evaluated $T^{-1}$ on arbitrary points in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$, not on the line $[-\infty, 0]$, as you thought I did. That's why I said "nice".

Comment: Yeah, they're the same point on the Riemann sphere (where all of this is properly formulated in the first place). For example, if you want $1/z$ to be a mobius transform sending $0$ to $\infty$, we need to be considering the Riemann sphere already (note limits from different directions give differently signed and scaled infinities, so we are forced to compactify and treat each infinity as the same to make the map well-defined)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.